# SQL Server: hidden "Sort" inserted in execution plan in left join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, execution

SQL 2017 Standard
i have a database in a star schema model (data warehouse)
to fill in a fact table, i have a stored procedure with a temporary table having around 470,0000 rows.
to fill in the dimension ids, i have a left join operation between the temporary table and the dimensions  tables.
for ex:

```
insert into factTable (...fields list...)
select t.Quantity1,t.Quantity2,d1.ID,d.ID,...,19.id from
MyTemp t
left outer join dim1 d1 on t.F1=d1.F1 and t.CompanyID=d1.CompanyID and t.DataSourceID=d1.DataSourceID
left outer join dim2 d2 on t.F2=d2.F2 and t.CompanyID=d2.CompanyID and t.DataSourceID=d2.DataSourceID
left outer join dim3 d3 on t.F3=d3.F3 and t.CompanyID=d2.CompanyID and t.DataSourceID=d2.DataSourceID
.......
left outer join dim19 d19 on t.F19=3.F19 and t.CompanyID=d19.CompanyID and t.DataSourceID=d19.DataSourceID
```

the problem is when using a smaller number of joins, for ex just for the first 5 or 6 dimensions, the query is very fast.

with 19 joins, it is taking more than 4 hours.

the execution plan shows that the bottleneck comes from a hidden "Sort" operation inserted by the query optimizer!!!!

when reading data from each dimension,  sql server is sorting the dimension data before joining with the temporary table.
introducing indexes on the temporary table did not solve the problem.
even limiting the query to the first field from an index on the temp table did not help

[image: Hidden Sort in execution plan]

[image: hidden sort - second picture]

Comment: Can you add the DDL for the dimension tables, including indexes?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical to performance.) PS Please use standard punctuation. Please use text for what can be given as text. Augment with images.

Comment: The DBMS sorts or indexes to avoid comparing all pairs of a row from each table of a join.

Comment: Hi David. I don't currently have access to the server where this is deployed. Will post this Monday morning asap. Thank you for your interest. Sorry for the delay but I will post the info ASAP as this is much important to me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
```

on the temporary table solved the problem.
Thank you all.
You can check [CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more details
(if you are working on SQL Server 2016 Standard edition you will need SP2)